# Convert a numeric variable to milisecond time format

Tags: tableau-api

i have a column in my dataset which consists of nuneric values: 15, 30, 45, .... 1000. How can i change the format to miliseconds in tableau in order to be recognised as a time series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert to a Datetime field you'll need to divide by 1000. The following Tableau Knowledge Base article explains in more detail:

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/dates-display-unix-epoch-instead-of-date-datetime

Be aware that the -8 in the second example in that kb article specifies the offset between GMT/UTC and the timezone used in the example (Pacific time). You may have a different offset in your data.